# How to create a new column converting date to text

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a new column with an `IF`.

If the difference between two dates is more than a month I have to use a text-like "much time" but if it is not I have to show a date.

So the date must be converted to a string to use a **text** column.
How can I convert date to text?

```
Fecha_real =
IF( DATEDIFF(ventas[fecha_pedido]; ventas[fecha]; month) = 1 ;
    "much time";
    ConvertToTextInSomeWay  ventas[fecha]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple with the [`FORMAT` function.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax). For example, `FORMAT(ventas[fecha], "Short Date")` will convert `fecha` into textlike `"12/31/2018"`.

That's just one format example. There are plenty of pre-defined and custom options if you'd rather something else. For example, `FORMAT(ventas[fecha], "dd-mm-yyyy")` would format that same date as `"31-12-2018"` instead.